# who can tell me how to write the SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is what I wrote：

```
$sql = "select * from tp_picture where (catid in(13,14,15,20) order by find_in_set(catid,'13,14,15,20')) order by listorder ASC";
```

first, order by find_in_set(catid,'13,14,15,20'))

next, order by field of tp_picture `listorder` .

who can tell me the correct SQL ,thinks.

Comment: This guy is pretty good - http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tom_Kyte

Comment: What database product is this for? Each vendor's RDBMS has a different flavour of Structured Query Language.

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker The presence of `find_in_set` indicates [tag:mysql]. Question is now tagged accordingly

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$sql = "select 
               *
        from 
                tp_picture 
        where 
                (catid in(13,14,15,20)) 
        order by 
                catid,listorder ASC";
```

try this

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you want then try to do it this way

```
select * 
  from tp_picture 
 where catid in(13, 14, 15, 20) 
 order by (find_in_set(catid, 13, 14, 15, 20) > 0) DESC, listorder
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM TP_PICTURE 
WHERE CAT_ID IN (13,14,15,20) AS 'CAT_ID'
ORDER BY CAT_ID, LISTORDER ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please, follow below syntex :
  select <column_name1, column_name2, ... >
       from table_name where <condition>
           order by <column_name1,...>
------------------------------------------------------------
    $sql = "select * from tp_picture 
    where catid in(13,14,15,20) 
    order by  catid , listorder ASC";
```